# 2007 Honda Civic Headlamp issue

Tags: honda, electrical

I have a 2007 Honda Civic LX.  The passenger side low beam isn't working.  The DRL does, which uses the same bulb.  I replaced the bulb first, assuming that was the problem,even knowing the HL didn't come on the dash indicating that was the problem.  I located the under dash fuse, #16 in the book, and it looked fine but replaced it anyways.  When I first changed the headlamp it worked for about a day (I only wiggled the wires under the dash/fuse area once) and turned the lights off.  Now it won't work.  Thanks for any advice guys (and girls)